# Stretch TextBlock to all available width

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm creating UWP application where one of the screens have layout like this:

```
<ListView>
    <ListViewItem>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Ellipse
                Width="32"
                Height="32"
                Margin="6"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Fill="LightGray" />
            <TextBlock
                Grid.Column="1"
                Margin="12,6,0,0"
                FontSize="20"
                Text="Here is Long Name" />
            <StackPanel
                Grid.Column="2"
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button Width="25" Height="45" BorderThickness="0">-</Button>
                <TextBlock
                    Width="25"
                    Height="45"
                    Padding="0,5,0,0"
                    FontSize="24"
                    Text="0"
                    TextAlignment="Center" />
                <Button Width="30" Height="45" BorderThickness="0">+</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Ellipse
                Width="32"
                Height="32"
                Margin="6"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Fill="LightGray" />
            <TextBlock
                Grid.Column="1"
                Margin="12,6,0,0"
                FontSize="20"
                Text="Short name" />
            <StackPanel
                Grid.Column="2"
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button Width="25" Height="45" BorderThickness="0">-</Button>
                <TextBlock
                    Width="25"
                    Height="45"
                    Padding="0,5,0,0"
                    FontSize="24"
                    Text="0"
                    TextAlignment="Center" />
                <Button Width="30" Height="45" BorderThickness="0">+</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

It looks like this (I'm not allowed to insert image): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Afvn6.png

I want that StackPanel in last column to be on the right side, no matter how long is name. I assume this will be the case if TextBlock stretches to all available width, but it doesn't. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to you ListView

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```